# How to record android screen with Android Studio?

Tags: android

I've installed Android Studio in the Applications folder on my Mac (I think the sdk is then in the package content), but now I want to record my screen for a demonstration video of an app with AShot.jar, and I have to give up the path to the SDK. When I give the path I think is right, it says the path Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk is not valid.

What to do?
Are there other ways to record your android screen?

Answer (score 49):

1. Connect your Device with your pc via usb.
2. Open android studio.Ensure that device is connected with adb.
3. Start click Screen Recording.
4. Screen Record can record the device display for a maximum of 3 minutes.

**Note:**

The Screen Record Works with  Real Android Device and some Emulators.

If the  button is in grey and un-clickable means that device not supports video capture.

The Screenshots from my system:

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Comment: That button is grey and unclickable for me :(

Comment: Work perfectly for me. Such a better option than Droid@Screen ! And so fluid ! ;-)

Comment: Also, ensure that the device supports video capture. If you get an empty video when attempting to record a video, you are probably trying to use a device that does not support video capture.

Comment: @user541905 only works for devices supporting screen capture (api21+ ?)

Comment: Nope. If I click Start Recording, it immediately stops, asks me where to save the file and then saves an empty file.

Comment: Best answer.. Thanks Bro... you saved my day...!

Comment: does this supports even the audio along with the video capture

Answer (score 5):

For those of us who need a ["Complete Idiot's Guide"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Idiot%27s_Guides) in order to find the elusive "Screen Record" button, here it is:

**First, make sure you have `LogCat` open** (Press F6, at least on OSx).

Then you might find that you still don't see any record button. Just hover on the tiny "overflow" arrow seen in the image below.

[image]

You should now see the record button, indicated in the image below.

[image]

Congratulations, if your device supports screen recording, just click the button and up will pop a dialog asking you to input resolution and bitrate (since this is an *"Idiot's Guide"*, just skip those and click "Start Recording"!).

Comment: i was about to start pulling my hair out looking for this button.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android 4.4 or higher you can use adb:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord

It can be found in the platform-tools folder under your sdk install folder.

Answer (score 1):

This point may be helpful for some one else 
All device do not support screen video recording with android studio. In this regard you can use emulator.

Comment: What are the devices supported in Recording?

Comment: follow @krishnan's answer. If your mobile supports video recording then screen record button will be visible if not it will be disabled. I actually don't know the specific list. But all latest version cell  supports this.

Comment: I can see record button.. Also I have recorded video.. But video is not playable... That's why asking

Comment: I think this is not a supporting problem. your mobile supports video record but not playable is a different issue. You have to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I am using the emulator and the button is disabled.

Comment: some one marked it down vote. Please see the date before doing it. This answer was right may be not now. thanks