# How to record screen with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-recording

I connect my phone to Android Studio and code. I want to record my phone screen. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701631/how-to-record-android-screen-with-android-studio) but that button is disabled in my Android Studio. I can capture screens but can't record. Can someone help me with this?

**UPDATE**

[image]

This is how it is there in my Android studio. The button is disabled

Comment: try another phone/an emulator

Comment: @harsh if my answer does not suit your problem please provide a screenshot of your Android Studio IDE

Comment: @Holmes I updated the question. thank you for help. I can not use your solution as button is disabled.

Comment: Are you debugging with a real phone or an AVD?

Comment: @Holmes it is phone. I saw that there are recorders and used a recorder. Thank you for help

Comment: BTW,, record function is available with physical devices only..

Comment: I faced this too. What I found is recorder is available in Marshmallow and not in older versions (e.g. JB)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe your device does not support the screen recorder, there are many devices which does not support screen recorder thus this is device issue. If you want to record your app screen then simply run the app on android emulator or on genymotion and start your desktop screen recorder and adjust the desktop screen to fit emulator. There are many screen recorder for PC but i prefer cam studio 8.
Thanks

Comment: For example... I use Genymotion and on once API16 devide the video recording button was disabled and on another one (API 19) is was enabled.

Comment: Doing this will show everything, (mouse cursor, which I don't want to see it in my record.)

Answer (score 94):

Now you can also record video from Android emulator to follow below option:

- Select **more** [image: more option]  option
- Then select **Record screen** [image: record screen] option.

Check below screenshot:

[image: Record android emulator screen]

Comment: Please can you show me how you setup that AVD. Basically all the AVD I launch doesn't have such feature. Maybe you do something special. Thanks again, I'll upvote, just in case.

Answer (score 44):

Go to your menu

- `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Android`

You will find the record icon at the bottom left corner.

[image]

If you are using an AVD, make sure "Use host GPU" is *disabled*.

To take a video recording of your app:

- Start your app as described in Run your App in Debug Mode.
- Click Android  to open the Android DDMS tool window.
- Click Screen Record  on the left side of the Android DDMS tool window.
- Click Start Recording.
- Interact with your app.
- Click Stop Recording.
- Enter a file name for the recording and click OK.

Source: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: "You will find the record icon". Yes, I found it, but it is inactive.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with another device? There any many devices that doesn't support screen recording after all.

Comment: You are assuming that record button is present for Emulator launches.

Comment: > If you are using an AVD, make sure "Use host GPU" is disabled.

Comment: How to enable circle where user clicked on screen?

Comment: For a Genymotion API 16 (Samsung Galaxy S2) the button was disabled for me.  But for an API 19 emulator (Google Nexus 4) the button is enabled.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is somehow linked with the API. But yes, there are devices  that doesn't support screen recording.

Comment: To my understanding, "Use host GPU" is no longer a setting for creating an AVD and now you must either choose a Graphics emulated performance dropdown option of "Hardware" or "Software". In this case, "Software" should let you screen record but it runs super slow.

Comment: Sometimes it also helps to restart Android Studio.

Comment: I don't have to clip Stop Recording, because it gets immediately automatically clicked by the application, and I get an empty file for my video.

Comment: @Trejkaz what's your device and your Studio version?

Comment: @Machado Huawei Watch, Android Studio 2.2.3, but was happening on the previous version I had installed from a whole year earlier too.

Comment: For those of you who have the icon disabled/inactive, try by **debugging** your app first, not just **running** it. The debugging icon is shown in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37205692/5452969

Comment: How do I disable "Use host GPU" ?

Answer (score 17):

In newer versions of `Android Studio` it **requires an external Android phone** to record screen from preferably with a resolution of at least `720p`. Since the internal runs on the virtual memory it can't be recorded and is therefore disabled as it can't both record and run emulator at same time. 
I'm running `Android Studio 2.3.2` which is the latest and the one I experienced this on. But when I closed the emulator and connected my `HTC One M9` it automatically enabled recording button to record the phone instead of the emulated device.
Check the images below and the difference between them in the red circles:

First image, *emulated device on the computer*:
[image: Emulated device not able to make a screen recording]

Second image, *personal device connected to computer*:
[image: Personal device connected and ready to be recorded from Android Studio]

Answer (score 17):

You can record videos from the command line into an .mp4 file:

`adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4`

When you are done recording, press Ctrl+C.

Then you can copy the file to your computer (current folder)

`adb pull /sdcard/video.mp4`

If you want you can delete the file from the sdcard

`adb shell rm /sdcard/video.mp4`

Comment: can't record audio in this method

Answer (score 9):

Android SDK Emulators don't support recording:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61682

The `screenrecord` command is simply missing:

```
i:\>adb -e shell
root@generic_x86_64:/ # screenrecord
/system/bin/sh: screenrecord: not found
127|root@generic_x86_64:/ #
```

On Windows I suggest using the **Fraps** generic screen capture tool as an alternative. It's an awesome tool with too many years of history to count. I'm not affiliated with them, I just used it "back in the day" when I was gaming a lot. On the Movies tab add a Video Capture Hotkey and use that to start/stop the recording. The FPS counter will be red while recording.

Comment: To add to this answer, [Prerequisites to Android Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html#byb) say that *the Video Capture tool works with a hardware device only, not the emulator*.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should just change a phone,like this:

When using HUAWEI,the screen record is disabled:

[image: Image1]

But when changing to Nubia, it works!

[image: Image2]

Comment: haha.. so simple!  I ran into this issue as I was developing with 2 devices both were the same brand and similar version.  When I selected the correct one suddenly the button was no longer disabled..  sigh!  yep, face + palm moment  :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It was solved when I didn't run but **debugged** de app.

[image: Debug icon in Android Studio IDE]

Once you have debugged your app, the icon will be enabled even if you just run your app without debugging.

I guess this has to be done for each app you develop, as it must be a *debugging feature* or something like that.

*Note that at this image I'm using Android Studio post 2.0, but when this problem happened to me I was using pre 2.0, so that should not matter.

Answer (score 3):

Open Android emilator,
Click to right sidebar more button "..."
Open new window, Record Screen and start record
It's OK 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html

Answer (score 3):

for those who never found screen recorder button or screenshot button. here you go

**First, make sure you have LogCat open (Press F6, at least on OSx).**

Then you might find that you still don't see any record button. Just hover on the tiny "overflow" arrow seen in the image below.

[image]

You should now see the record button, indicated in the image below.

[image]

Congratulations, if your device supports screen recording, just click the button and up will pop a dialog asking you to input resolution and bitrate

Answer (score 2):

**Record video from Android emulator**

As a workaround for MacOS users

```
Open QuickTime Player -> File -> New Screen Recording
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real device run it in debug mode and then go to the Logcat view there will be a screen recording button on the left.

Answer (score 0):

stupid mistake I made was I had two android devices connected.
And I was recording off the locked one so my video was always 18mb and black screen and wouldnt play in quicktime.

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio Arctic Fox They have moved this functionality to the logcat
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video

Answer (score 0):

From the Mac, `Command Option R` in any emulator from Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 2 | Electric Eel.

Note that it doesn't record into a QuickTime format but instead instead WebM or (shudder) GIF.

Also, it doesn't record the device frame around the screen contents either if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

For **Visual Studio** users:
`Tools -> Android -> Android Adb Command Prompt...`

In the opened CMD window use following commands from *Rondev*'s answer:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4
adb pull /sdcard/video.mp4
adb shell rm /sdcard/video.mp4
```

Answer (score -1):

In case of emulator I experienced that you should install [DirectX End-User Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35)

Installed it for another application and luckily also Android Sceer Record is working fine and isn't greyed out!

Hope this help some other people