# Is there a way to record the phone screen using ARCore SDK?

Tags: android, arcore

I want to record phone screen in a video format.

Is there a way to record my screen using ARcore android SDK??

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: I would like to take a video with the AR object in it. It's like a camera recording video

Comment: Is this a feature that you want to provide in your app, or you just want to record the screen so that you can post the video somewhere?

Comment: yes I want post the video to server , I don't want record the screen ,I only want record the GLSurfaceView .

Comment: how I can take picture and record video like use camera

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the recording functionality to be built into your app? If not, just use something like the [DU Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duapps.recorder) App. Worked well for me for recording Google Tango Apps. Haven't tested it with ARCore, but should work as well.

Comment: I would like to take a video with the AR object in it. It's like a camera recording video

Comment: I can confirm this solution works. It works great in AR! Thx Steffen F!

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this works for you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31547690/855984

The only thing that sucks about it is that you'll need to be tethered via USB cable to control the recording.

Android Studio will sample whatever it is you are seeing on your device provided that you're the owner of the process. Won't work for ripping other stuff visuals like Netflix for example.

Comment: I would like to take a video with the AR object in it. It's like a camera recording video

Comment: Have you attempted recording it with the tools you have available in Android Studio?

Comment: I don't understand , I want record the glsurfaceview  to .mp4 file,after post to server

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to record the phone screen by using a recordablesurfaceview in place of the GLSurfaceView. see: https://github.com/UncorkedStudios/recordablesurfaceview. The OnDrawFrame is called twice by recordablesurfaceview, once to render to the screen and the second time to record the video. Once the video is saved you can upload it to the server as you desire.

Comment: This solution does not use the ARcore android SDK as desired.

Comment: Its not native ARcore but it is the closest i have found to be "ARCore-like" and that does not require heavy investment in custom code