# Create NavigationDrawer in Fragment, NOT Activity

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

Would like to know how to create a NavigationDrawer within a Fragment (in this case my HomeFragment) and NOT in an Activity. Have seen everything on how to create a NavigationDrawer within an Activity, such as MainActivity, but my goal for this project is to create a NavigationDrawer ONLY for the HomeFragment. Don't want any of the other fragments to contain it. The drawer_menu will contain Edit Profile, Settings, and Log Out. Below I have posted what I have done... Is there a better way to do it? Code seems to be a bit awkward.

Every video I have seen, every post has been about creating a NavigationDrawer in Activities, so I'm wondering what the code would look like for Fragment. I tried doing it just like you would for Activity, but it wouldn't work.

Below you guys have my HomeFragment.java and fragment_home.xml

```
fragment_home.xml


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".Fragment.HomeFragment"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home_fragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/events_logo_main_activity"
                                android:layout_width="180dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/events_logo_black_max_size" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/camera_create_an_event_main_activity"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_create_events_home_fragment_black" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/three_bars_settings_main_activity"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_three_bars_settings_home_fragment_black" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bar">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryAqua50"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
package com.e.events.Fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.e.events.Adapter.PostAdapter;
import com.e.events.EditProfileActivity;
import com.e.events.MainActivity;
import com.e.events.Model.Post;
import com.e.events.PostActivity;
import com.e.events.R;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageView options;

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<Post> postLists;

    private ImageView camera_create_event;

    private List<String> followingList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        postLists = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postLists);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);

        options = view.findViewById(R.id.three_bars_settings_main_activity);

        options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home_fragment);

        drawer = view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        camera_create_event = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_create_an_event_main_activity);

        camera_create_event.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        checkFollowing();

        return view;
    }

    private void checkFollowing() {
        followingList = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Follow")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child("following");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                followingList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    followingList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }

                readPosts();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readPosts() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postLists.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    for (String id : followingList) {
                        if (post.getPublisher().equals(id)) {
                            postLists.add(post);
                        }
                    }
                }

                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There's really nothing different, doing it in a `Fragment`, other than the normal changes you'd make when moving any `Activity` setup to a `Fragment`. Are you having any issues?

Comment: @Mike M I am having issues with the Toggle Option as vivek said down below. So I just planted a normal icon and set and onClick option for it in the fragment which seems to work fine, but did want the toggle option and onBackPressed also doesn't seem to work. Don't know if you have any insight on any of these points?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what problems you're having with the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, as you've not shown how you set it up. It can work just fine in a `Fragment`, however. Here's an small example that demonstrates that: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17HMw4W_s_nOJIdyl8yGoQD4AVAvt8lFd/view?usp=drivesdk. Aside from that, I'm not sure what you mean by "onBackPressed also doesn't seem to work".

Comment: @MikeM. mike any idea as to why the drawerLayout might be making my toolbar bounce? I did everything as described in the xml file above and Im 100 certain that the drawerLayout is responsable for making the toolbar bounce up and down when I switch to the home fragment from other fragments... any clue as to why that is?

Comment: I'd have to see the specific behavior to even begin to guess. Can you record it, and link to it here in a comment? [Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468342/2850651), [Hardware](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video).

Comment: @MikeM. it wasn't working out so I just created the NavigationDrawer in the MainActivity and now everything is fine. Only problem is I didn't want it to be in every fragment, just homefragment, but at least the toolbar doesn't bounce now.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible.
Because To implement the Navigation Drawer we first need to add android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout as the root of the activity layout.
For Toggle Option of Navigation Drawer, We Require ToolBar.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```

The ToolBar is not possible in the fragment.
For Better use, Make Navigation View in Activity inside the DrawerLayout.

Comment: The `<DrawerLayout>` does not have to be the `Activity`'s root layout. And there is no restriction that prevents the use of `Toolbar` in a `Fragment`.

Comment: @Mike M.   Can you give me any reference code of it or any example of it?

Comment: @VivekModi okay man, yeah you're absolutely right the toggle option doesn't work for the opening of the drawer and also onBackPressed doesn't work either, but I DO have a toolbar in my HomeFragment which you can see about in the xml file... You recommend I make a separate activity that extends to all the fragments? Maybe there is a way to do that but disactivate the navigationDrawer for the other fragments where I don't want to use it?

Comment: I missed the notification for your comment to me, but if you're still interested, I posted a link to a simple example in a comment on the question.

Comment: @MikeM. okay perfect thanks a lot I'm looking at it now and trying to figure it out! Thanks man!!!